# Multi Select Drop Down Using chosen.jquery.js

Tags: jquery-chosen

when i select index 0 then all Previously selected item should be remove. Is this possible? i have multiple chosen drop down in same page...i have tried so many things but didn't get the proper solutions yet.

Comment: please put some code here so that we can know what you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. If it is multiple select, it means you can select "multiple" items, otherwise it's a normal select. Also see [this](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and check out if it provides something helpful for you.

Comment: I have multiple select drop down in this i want to clear all selected item when i select index zero(0). like i have Select Country at the index zero so when i select zero index then all selected county should be remove and 'select  Country' should be there as selected.